# Restrict FB app install to premium accounts of my website

Tags: facebook

I am developing a FB application that i want only some users of my website (premium) can access and install on their company FB brand page.

What i need to achive is similar to what Getsatisfaction and Uservoice are doing with their apps, that only premium accounts can see in their dashboard, do you mind how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When the user purchases you application you need to ask him to access his pages, then you save them to an helper table.

After that you'll send them to the install dialog.

Your page tab index will need to have a roadblock, where you check if the page accessing the app (that you can get trough the signed_request) is allowed (if it is in the helper table), otherwise you block the application.

Am I making myself clear?

Anything let me know.

Comment: What you say requires that i do a check on the FB page of the user and save it in a table, instead what i'm looking for is to do a ckeck on the user account type (free or premium) and based on that allow him or not to install the app on his page.